# Animating (Non-Stop) jQuery Ui Slider On Button Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/AWKaFe6AMi) and let me know how I can dynamically run the slider from value to max and back to min and again ...

```js
  $(function() {
    var slider = $( "#slider" ).slider({
     range: "min",
  min: 1,
  max: 280,
   value: 140
    
    });

$('.btn-succes').on('click',function(){
    slider.slider('value', slider.slider('value') );
    return false;
});
    
      });
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/images/ui-bg_flat_10_000000_40x100.png)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="col-md-2">
     <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  
  <button class="btn btn-success">Run</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info">Stop</button>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` for the animation aspect. As the slider updates, you can check the current value of the slider by subscribing to the `slidechange` event and calling `$("#slider").slider("value")`. I've renamed the buttons in my example to better describe their actions.

Click **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/p6zcww6p/)** for a demo.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<button class="btn btn-run">Run</button>
<button class="btn btn-stop">Stop</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
//Global values.
var increment = 1;
var slideMax = 100;
var animationDelay = 50;
var sliderVal = 0;
var sliderInterval = {};

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    animate: "fast",
    max: slideMax
  });
});

//Subscribe to the "slidechange" event to keep track of the slider value.
$("#slider").on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
  //If the slider value reaches the max, set the interval to -1 to start animating backwards.
  if ($("#slider").slider("value") == slideMax) {
    increment = -1;
  } else if ($("#slider").slider("value") == 0) {
    increment = 1;
  }
});

$(".btn-run").on("click", function() {
  //Set the slider value to the current value to start the animation at the correct point.
  sliderVal = $("#slider").slider("value");
  sliderInterval = setInterval(function() {
    sliderVal += increment;
    $("#slider").slider("value", sliderVal);
  }, animationDelay);
});

$(".btn-stop").on("click", function() {
  //Call clearInterval to stop the animation.
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});
```